# How to install wifi card in parrot security OS

Tags: linux, operating-systems, wifi-driver

I just installed 'Parrot Security OS' on my computer.
After installation I am not able to access WI-FI .
There is no WI-FI  option at all.
I am currently using HP pavilion 15-p206tx laptop, which is having broadcom network/WI-FI driver in windows 8.1 OS.
I installed 'Parrot Security OS' as dual boot.
I updated the 'Parrot Security OS' by

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get update && upgrade
```

Also updated all the software's .
Can anybody answer me how to install WI-FI card/driver in Parrot Security OS.
And how to get WI-FI option in it.

Comment: have you tried running those commands on `su` mood?

Comment: Yeah. I tried as root user.